# Django nested inline TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, nested, render, inlines

### The Error

I'm trying to use the [django-nested-inline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nested-inline/0.3.4) package. It seems like everything works but when I try to create a new `Course` with the admin website I get the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/courses/course/5/

admin/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html
```

But of course, `admin/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html` only doesn't exist because there was an error during template rendering:

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\...\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_form.html, error at line 62

admin/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html

60 {% block inline_field_sets %}
61 {% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
62     {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
63 {% endfor %}
64 {% endblock %}
```

As you can see, something messes up when Django tries to render

`{% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}`

### My Code

Here's my `admin.py`, but I don't think it really has anything to do with the above error:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin
from courses.models import Course, Skill, Note

class NoteInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Note
    extra = 0

class SkillInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Skill
    extra = 0
    inlines = [NoteInline]

class CourseAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SkillInline]

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

And here's my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Course Description')
    course_subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='No Subject')

    def num_skills(self):
        return len(self.skill_set.all())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

class Skill(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skill_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Skill Description')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.skill_name

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

class Note(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    note_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='...note text...')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.note_text

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

### Things I've Noticed

- [django-nested-inline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nested-inline/0.3.4) was updated from 0.3.3 to 0.3.4 two days ago. The updated version "added licence and updated for python 3". I'm using 0.3.4, but also Python 2.7, not Python 3. However, I uninstalled 0.3.4, installed 0.3.3, and tried again. This didn't work and produced the same error. I've since uninstall 0.3.3 and reinstall 0.3.4.
- The admin site and the site itself doesn't crash, just when I try to add a new `Course` via the admin site.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your nested_inline app is not installed or django would be able to find the templates.
Either that or add the templates to a directory referenced by your TEMPLATE_DIRS setting or change the template name for your inlines.

Per the usage in the link you provided: Add nested_inline to INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete [ESPmorph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573026/espmorph) answer:

You need to add ALL the apps that you wish to use templates from, in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` list inside `project/main_app/settings.py` like so:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    "nested_inline",
]
```

This is indicated in [django-nested-inline](https://pypi.org/project/django-nested-inline/0.3.4/) doc:

> Usage: Add nested_inline to INSTALLED_APPS

You need to do that for all your own custom apps AND all your third party apps as well, like with django-nested-inline (add *nested_inline*) or django-polymorphic (add *polymorphic*) for instance.